# Page numbering font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm deeply looking for the font used for `4 of 4` in this page numbering.

[image: page numbering]

It's the page numbering style of the [Adforn documentation](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/fonts/adforn/doc/fonts/adforn/adforn.pdf).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the CM font in italic shape: `\textit{4 of 4}`

Comment: From the pdf we find LMRoman-Italic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[cf]{\itshape \adforn{18} \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage} \adforn{46}}
\usepackage{adforn}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]